# When is a degree required? or: hai6 vs hou2 vs gei

Tags: grammar, cantonese, spoken

I am trying to learn Cantonese.

I want to be able to say (speak, not write) after a meal:

> I am full.

Which I could translate directory to:

> Ngo5 hai6 baau2

But, my local (student in HK) friend says this is incorrect and that the following is preferred:

> Ngo5 hou2 baau2

Which I would read as

> I very full

Sentences like this come up quite often, where sometimes I need to say the verb hai6, or sometimes a "degree" such as hou2 and additionally gei(unsure of tone or meaning) has been suggested.

What is the correct structure of a sentence where you want to tell somebody your current state of being?

Comment: You wouldn't use *hai6* to tell people you are tired or hungry or thirty or full - you would use *hai6* to tell people you are a doctor or a teacher or a principle or a big brother. *hou2* while seemingly meaning *very* is often used with things like tired or hungry or thirty or full to make the sentence more natural and understandable - you shouldn't take it literally. Like your friend suggested Ngo5 hou2 baau2 just means I'm full.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ngo5 hai6 baau2

--> 我係飽 is "unnatural", hmmm, non-native way to express.

> ngo5 hou2 baau2

--> 我好飽

native way to say it :)

just like the english "being", in other language, the verb changes:

**i'm 70 years old**

(being is used to describe age), which is translated to:

**j'ai 70 ans**

(avoir [to have], is used, not être [to be]; then, in cantonese, it should be:

**我七十歲**

technically, the verb is omitted

> gei(unsure of tone or meaning)

it is 嘅(u+5605), roughly "my, his, her, their"; ask you friend how to pronounce it ;-)

last, i would suggest learning cantonese from dramas, videos, and news, forget grammar books.

have fun :)

Comment: Hmm I think I must have misheard/misremembered gei then, I thought it maybe "a little"? As in: I am a little hungry. Thanks for the response! Not sure if you happen to know Spanish or not, but it seems like hai6 vs hou2 is similar to ser vs estar?

Comment: spanish? no lah :( "i am a little hungry" would be: 我有啲餓. 啲(u+5572) means "a little", pronounced similar to "d" in "a, b, c, d", according to english. http://humanum.arts.cuhk.edu.hk/Lexis/lexi-mf/search.php?word=啲